# Helmet CSP Not Working in Safari Browsers

Tags: node.js, express, content-security-policy, helmet.js

Has anyone else had any problems with Helmet's content security policy in Safari?

https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet

```js
app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
  directives: {
    defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
    scriptSrc: ["'self'",'code.jquery.com','cdnjs.cloudflare.com'],
    styleSrc: ["'self'","'unsafe-inline'",'fonts.googleapis.com','cdnjs.cloudflare.com'],
    imgSrc: ["'self'"],
    fontSrc: ['fonts.googleapis.com','fonts.gstatic.com','cdnjs.cloudflare.com'],
    connectSrc: [],
  },

  reportOnly:false,
  setAllHeaders: false,
  disableAndroid: false

}));
```

This works fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE. But I am getting these errors in Safari.

[Safari Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jL00G.png)

[image: Safari Errors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari requires you to specify the scheme since it does not allow upgrades to `https` per the spec. Instead, it defaults to the scheme of the current page - I'm assuming you're viewing the page on `http`. Instead of allowing `http`, I'd specify:

```
styleSrc: ["'self'","'unsafe-inline'",'https://fonts.googleapis.com','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com'],
```

OR **require `https` for all traffic**. Do not use the `http:` scheme in your policy :smile:

This may be fixed on the latest version of safari (haven't tested), but that wouldn't change my suggestion on what to do (so you don't break things).

https://twitter.com/Scott_Helme/status/642630334983614464

Comment: That was it! Thanks for the solution!